# How can I change the default camera app (on lockscreen)?

Tags: lock-screens, camera, default-applications, open-source

I would like to uninstall the default camera app and instead use the FOSS [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera&hl=en). And I would also like to access the camera from the lockscreen.

How can I do this in Android 6?

Comment: Thank you but I don't have my phone rooted. If I need to keep the standard camera that's fine too as long as I can change the default camera app.

Answer (score 4):

While uninstalling the pre-installed camera app can be difficult as others have mentioned, it should be relatively easy to change your default camera app to Open Camera (or whatever camera app you prefer). I prefer Open Camera as well, so I also wanted the same thing.

To make Open Camera the default (or any camera app other than the pre-installed version), follow these steps:

1. Download camera app of choice (in your case, Open Camera)
2. Wait until it installs.
3. Turn off screen with power button (don't turn off phone, just screen), turn screen back on but stay on lockscreen (don't unlock phone).
4. Select camera from lock screen (Image 1 below).
5. Unlock phone if it requests for you to do so.
6. A pop-up should appear. Choose your desired camera app in the list.

   - IF you have the ability in this menu, select "Always." (Image 2)
   - IF you do not have the ability to select "Always" for the preferred camera app, still select desired app, let app open, go back to lockscreen. Repeat process, the second time you can choose "Always" for your preferred camera app. (Images 3 and 4)
7. Your phone should launch your preferred app now by default.

Caveats: sometimes when either camera app updates, you have to do the process again. Usually it doesn't happen too often, only when big changes occur to the apps. Hope that helps!

---

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]

---

[image: Image 3] [image: Image 4]

Comment: For those who already set the stock camera as the lock screen camera default, how do you clear the lock screen camera default so that you can set the default again?  (no way to disable system camera app on asus zenfone 4 max zc554kl)

Comment: Same problem as @JonGrah on Samsung S7, can't find any option to reset it.

Answer (score 3):

- Default camera is a system app, which requires root to uninstall default camera app. You can use Titanium Backup like app to remove system app (N.B: Removing system app will be harmful to your device).
- Settings->Security, under device security, tap on settings icon near screen lock. Select Lock screen shortcuts. Tap on any left or right default icons, prompts to choose action: tap on select application. Tap on Apps on top, and select your required camera app(These setting is on Lineage 14.1 android nougat)

Answer (score 0):

Android keeps changing how you can remove an app that's been set as the default for an action. Currently my phone is using Android 11; here, you need to go to:

1. Preferences
2. Apps and notifications
3. See all apps
4. Camera
5. Advanced
6. Open by default
7. Clear defaults

There are also some apps that will show you the default app for all the various categories and skip you to this spot in preferences directly, which I find more convenient so I don't have to remember this long navigation tree.

Once you've done this, you can open the camera app via your normal shortcut (eg pressing power button twice on my phone) and you'll get the dialog that asks which app you'd like to use for that action in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do this without rooting your device, then I may have an answer (that has worked for me) on Android 12. So, you cannot uninstall the default camera app, but what you *can* do is disable it. And really, that's all you have to do in order to use another camera app as the default one (and I would guess that it works only if you don't have other camera apps.) This has worked for me when using ProShot on Motorola Moto G stylus 5g (2022).

Comment: Well, doesn't work for me on Samsung Galaxy S23+ (Android 14). Even with system camera disabled (which cannot be done from UI, but needs `adb shell pm disable-user com.sec.android.app.camera`) or even uninstalled; the result is that lock screen camera icon disappears, double-clicking on power button does not work, and apps trying to take pictures via camera intents return `No camera installed` instead. Even if I have OpenCamera installed (which worked perfectly fine as default camera on Android 10 and below).